# Place cursor at the end of new image instead of before

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextstorage

I am creating an app where users add images and text together in a UITextView and share with friends.
I have been successful in adding the images and text together thanks to other `StackExchange` users. I'm now facing a minor problem with the cursor positioning.

When I insert text, the cursor moves as expected. However, when I add image, the cursor remains behind the image (that is, end of last inserted text). Below is my code. How can I move the cursor to the end of the newly inserted image so that newly added text/image appends to the right and not left.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(25, 25));
let img = UIImage(named:change_arr[indexPath.row]);
img?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25));
let img1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Create a NSTextAttachment object which will hold the created emoji
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment();
// Attach the emoji to the NSTextAttachment object
    textAttachment.image = img1;

// Create an NSAttributedString object to hold any dynamic data like the created emoji
var attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment);

// Add the NSAttributedString to the current position of the cursor
message.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attributedString, atIndex: message.selectedRange.location);
```

Edited: I have found the solution to the problem.

I only had to add one to the `selectedRange.location` like this:
    textView.selectedRange.location += 1

Comment: Speaking from OSX there is a TextEditor which keeps a selected range you can modify.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I will be very grateful if you could elaborate on that a bit. Am still pretty new to iOS programming. This is actually my first app. How do I modify the selected range?

Comment: The class `message` to where you add is likely NSText, correct?